# Windows Phone Development Tax Profile

Tags: windows-phone

I am an individual developer from Turkey. I have no company or business. I got a developer account. I try to submit paid app to platform, windows phone. However, it says it is required to fill out tax form. I don't have any tax advisor or a man who helps me about these forms. I don't have any address in US. Why I cannot submit application to store? Any idea about these forms?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the blog post from Antoine Leblond [Getting paid from the Windows Store](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/08/03/getting-paid-from-the-windows-store.aspx), it walks you through the steps of how to fill out the tax form for most basic cases.

The part interesting for you is `For international developers filling out a W-8 form`